# cannot open dataset in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, dataset

I am writing ASP.NET C# web-project and I created DataSet and several table adapters and MySQL queries.

Suddenly, computer turned off and when turned on it again and opened my project in Visual Studio I couldn't open my DataSet in constructor. DataSet opens only in code like below:

[image]

Does someone know how to open DataSet in Constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on it and choose `Open With` - and from there choose `DataSet Editor`

Alternatively reset VS settings - `devenv /resetskippkgs` from VS command prompt